# how to switch from android app to web?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to switch from my app to a web site (http://translate.google.com/) just clicking on a button something like this

```
public void gotoMyWebSite(View view){
//goto my site using a url 
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Pass the intent to open the web view of your url

Comment: -1 : Please google little bit

Comment: Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",Uri.parse(o.get("url")));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void gotoMyWebSite(View view) {
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://translate.google.com/"));
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understood you correctly you need something like this

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://translate.google.com/"));
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

put this snipped in your onclick listener

Note:
you will need an internet permission defined in your manifest

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this in your Button's onClick event,

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

            }
        });
```